# Java ResultSet already closed exception while querying user data

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

As I've started in the title, while I'm querying for user data in my java application, I get following message: *"Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed"*.

I know that this is happens if you try to have more ResultSets opened at the same time.

Here is my current code:

App calls getProject("..."), other 2 methods are there just for help. I'm using 2 classes because there is much more code, this is just one example of exception I get.

*Please note that I've translated variable names, etc. for better understanding, I hope I didn't miss anything.*

```
/* Class which reads project data */

public Project getProject(String name) {
    ResultSet result = null;
    try {
        // executing query for project data
        // SELECT * FROM Project WHERE name=name
        result = statement.executeQuery(generateSelect(tProject.tableName,
                "*", tProject.name, name));
        // if cursor can't move to first place,
        // that means that project was not found
        if (!result.first())
            return null;
        return user.usersInProject(new Project(result.getInt(1), result
                .getString(2)));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (BadAttributeValueExpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        // closing the ResultSet
        try {
            if (result != null)
                result.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
}

/* End of class */

/* Class which reads user data */

public Project usersInProject(Project p) {
    ResultSet result = null;
    try {
        // executing query for users in project
        // SELECT ID_User FROM Project_User WHERE ID_Project=p.getID()
        result = statement.executeQuery(generateSelect(
                tProject_User.tableName, tProject_User.id_user,
                tProject_User.id_project, String.valueOf(p.getID())));

        ArrayList<User> alUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
        // looping through all results and adding them to array
        while (result.next()) { // here java gets ResultSet closed exception
            int id = result.getInt(1);
            if (id > 0)
                alUsers.add(getUser(id));
        }
        // if no user data was read, project from parameter is returned
        // without any new user data
        if (alUsers.size() == 0)
            return p;
        // array of users is added to the object,
        // then whole object is returned
        p.addUsers(alUsers.toArray(new User[alUsers.size()]));
        return p;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return p;
    } finally {
        // closing the ResultSet
        try {
            if (result != null)
                result.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
}

public User getUser(int id) {
    ResultSet result = null;
    try {
        // executing query for user:
        // SELECT * FROM User WHERE ID=id
        result = statement.executeQuery(generateSelect(tUser.tableName,
                "*", tUser.id, String.valueOf(id)));
        if (!result.first())
            return null;
        // new user is constructed (ID, username, email, password)
        User usr = new user(result.getInt(1), result.getString(2),
                result.getString(3), result.getString(4));
        return usr;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (BadAttributeValueExpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        // closing the ResultSet
        try {
            if (result != null)
                result.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
}

/* End of class */
```

Statements from both classes are added in constructor, calling connection.getStatement() when constructing each of the classes.

tProject and tProject_User are my enums, I'm using it for easier name handling. generateSelect is my method and should work as expected. I'm using this because I've found out about prepared statements after I have written most of my code, so I left it as it is.

I am using latest java MySQL connector (5.1.21).

I don't know what else to try. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have more than one class accessing the DB?

Comment: Yes, as I've described in the example of how it should work, there is one class, which is reading project data and another, which is reading user data.

Comment: OK. First off, I know it sounds dumb, but are all the resources on the other class being closed? If you can, try to use the same connection objects for both classes. Also, are you running them in Threads? I doubt, just asking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from @aroth's answer:

There are many situations in which a `ResultSet` will be automatically closed for you. To quote the official documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

```
A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated 
it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of 
multiple results.
```

Here in your code , You are creating new `ResultSet` in the method `getUser` using the same `Statement` object which created result set in the `usersInProject` method which results in closing your resultset object in the method `usersInProject`.

**Solution:**
Create another statement object and use it in  `getUser` to create resultset.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Now I'm creating new statement at beginning of every method which works with ResultSets. That might be more resource (memory and CPU) consuming, but at least it works for me now. And resources consumption doesn't really matter to me that much as I'm only going to run this at my computer.

Comment: @maremp: You should accept the helpful answer by Clicking on correct sign. Read more at http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 5):

It's not really possible to say definitively what is going wrong without seeing your code.  However note that there are many situations in which a `ResultSet` will be *automatically* closed for you.  To quote the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object
>   that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next
>   result from a sequence of multiple results.

Probably you've got one of those things happening.  Or you're explicitly closing the `ResultSet` somewhere before you're actually done with it.

Also, have you considered using an ORM framework like Hibernate?  In general something like that is much more pleasant to work with than the low-level JDBC API.

Comment: "... used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results." That would probably be the case. As I'm reading users in project, there are more results, therefore I'm using method next(), which to go through all. I'm also closing the ResultSet after returning object(s), in the finally block.

Comment: @maremp - Please reread the first sentence of this Answer ... :-)

Comment: yes, @maremp simply you doing something after ResultSet is closed and this "something" is not allowed so you need to find point where your ResultSet is going to close and fix it.

Comment: I have updated my question and added my code, I hope this will help you to answer why I get the error